# Google Chrome crashing when start download

Tags: google-chrome, 13.04

I got a strange problem with ubuntu 13.04 and **google-chrome**

Google chrome keeps crashing when i download something. And i can't see detailed chrome log because chrome://crashes/ is disabled and it also crashing when i go to **settings** section on google-hrome

here is my crash log on /var/log/syslog

```
kernel: [11860.628097] chrome[3352]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fd8552b3f14 sp 00007fffa7e510a0 error 4 in chrome[7fd85426a000+519e000]
```

google-chrome Version: 26.0.1410.63

ubuntu: 13.04

also i tried to disable all my plugins from **chrome://extensions/**

,thanks

Comment: Segfaults are usually indicative of some type of bug in the software.  A bug should be filed with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the user profile of your Google Chrome and then use chrome again

User profile is present in the following folder, delete the google-chrome folder.

```
~/.config/google-chrome/
```

Keep in mind that deleting these profiles will wipe out any bookmarks, cookies, etc. attached to that profile. If you’re using Chrome Sync, there’s no need to back up anything as it will all be restored for you the next time you start Chrome and login to the Sync system.

You can read these instruction at [Google Chrome help for reseting profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059)

Answer (score 2):

You might not need to delete your whole user profile. I was able to fix this by deleting my download history alone: Downloads > Clear All.

I diagnosed this [as per these instructions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237107#c7):

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.config/chromium/Default/History

sqlite> select count(*) from downloads;
sqlite> select count(*) from downloads_url_chains;
```

The two counts differed, suggesting that the database had become corrupt. I backed it up (you never know) then cleared the download history. Chromium hasn't crashed since.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226002

see the comments in the bug report.

You might want to switch to canary channel for Chrome, or you have to wait until the patch reaches the stable channel.

Comment: That issue seems to be about a dependency problem? How it is related?